# Horizontal Scrolling with side content scaling on iOS

Tags: ios, scroll

I'm having problem solving how to get an effect like Duolingo's carousel scrolling of content. The effect is that the card in the middle would be the largest with ones on the sides some in and out as it [image: Here is a pic of it]

Has anyone done this or have an idea?

Comment: What is your approach to this? What have you tried and what has not worked?

Comment: I'm using a UIScrollview and just adding content, and pages by the frame of the scrollview..

Comment: You might want to turn your attention to the classical [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) control. It would allow you to replicate the 3D effect you want after some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by implementing some of the [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) methods. `scrollViewDidScroll:` will provide you with continuous events during the scroll and you should be able to calculate the scale of the buttons/images from this point.